# How to start Chrome with webdriver and quic disabled?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to start chrome with webdriver with quic disabled as follow:

```
--flag-switches-begin --disable-quic --flag-switches-end
```

I am using python with selenium 2.47.3

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("--disable-quic")
_browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Doing that does not put --disable-quic in between --flags-switches-begin and end.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is still looking for this, the correct way to do this is:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("disable-quic")  # not "--disable-quic"
_browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```